# Cannot commit change in SQL developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle11gr2

I changed data in table field and then I clicked on the "COMMIT" icon. The data was not updated and I saw this message from the Data Editor-log.

```
One error saving changes to table "EVO"."T_CAP_SUM":
```

However, when I used a query, the data has been updated.

```
UPDATE T_CAP_SUM SET FCNT_004 = '0' WHERE CELL_NO = 'MAT-02'
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Did you try refreshing the result set before making the edit?

Comment: No. I edit data without refreshing.

Comment: so refresh the result set then....

Comment: It same result. The data was not update.

Comment: What was shown after "One error saving changes to table "EVO"."T_CAP_SUM":"?

Comment: Nothing. There is the auto-gen query above that message. <br/>`UPDATE "EVO"."T_CAP_SUM" SET FCNT_001 = '0' WHERE ROWID = 'AAASNPAABAAAU+IAAD' AND ORA_ROWSCN = '1168566'  One error saving changes to table "EVO"."T_CAP_SUM":`

Comment: It's not a global temporary table is it?

Comment: I think it is not one.

Comment: What happens if you run that generated update statement?

Comment: Row has been update. May SQL developer not allow to edit value directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In some cases SQL Developer's method of updating with a predicate on ROW_SCN doesn't work. In these cases you can often workaround the problem by unchecking the "Use ORA_ROWSCN" option, via *Tools* -> *Preferences*, *Database* -> *ObjectViewer*. This option is available in recent versions of SQL Developer (including 4.0).

Comment: Sorry. I not found your option.

Comment: @Monkawee, what version of SQL Developer are you using? The ORA_ROWSCN option is under *Tools* -> *Preferences*, *Database* -> *ObjectViewer*. Might be worth trying.

Comment: @jeffrey, Version 1.5.5. but, under Database option is ObjectViewer Parameter. Are you mean that? If that true. The ORA_ROWSCN not exists.

Comment: Perhaps you need to upgrade to a supported version - it's now up to version 4.0...

Comment: @JeffreyKemp, I not need to upgrade now. However, I would like to accept your answer. Thank you.

Comment: You can accept Sagar's answer, it's got the details now.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if your row is having date type column or not. If yes then check whether date is in correct format or not. As incorrect date format can also result in above mentioned error